# Get windows events for a day

Tags: windows, powershell, event-viewer, error-logging

I'm trying to create a **PowerShell Cmdlet** that runs daily and shows me the errors that occured on the previous day.

I can make it show the last 100. Instead I'd like to see just the one that occured the day before.

```
get-eventlog 
 -logname application 
 -newest 100 | 
 select eventid,machinename,entrytype,message,source,timegenerated,username | 
 export-clixml C:\Logs.xml
```

Comment: The instructions for get-eventlog are available at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849834.aspx and fully answer your question.

Comment: Which one do you want it to show?

Comment: the event for the day @ChrisInEdmonton i want it to get within a time period of 1 day. i'd previously that article and it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This PowerShell command will return the event logs for the previous 24 hours:

`Get-EventLog Application -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)`